# Print date with alternative calendar

Tags: c, winapi

I'm developing a program in C for Windows. How can I print a date using an alternative calendar (e.g., Hijri)?
I tried to use the EnumCalendarInfoExEx() function and obtain the alternative calendar for a specific locale, for example:

```
BOOL CALLBACK myCallback(LPWSTR lpCalendarInfoString, CALID  Calendar, LPWSTR lpReserved, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (iIteration == 1) {
        iAlternativeCal = _wtoi(lpCalendarInfoString);
    }
    iIteration++;
    return 1;
}    

EnumCalendarInfoExEx(myCallback, L"tr-TR", ENUM_ALL_CALENDARS, NULL, CAL_ICALINTVALUE, NULL);
```

With this code I am able to obtain the Calendar ID = 6 which is associated to Hijiri calendar.
How can I use this information to print a date for Hijiri calendar (e.g. 20 Safar 1445 Hijri for September 5, 2023)?

Comment: I think you will find that support for these functions is very limited in Windows. Your best bet is finding a library to handle this conversion and formatting (and parsing?)

Comment: I don't know about alternative calendars, but to print a date you can use `GetDateFormat[Ex]()`. The documentation for that function will probably lead you down the correct path

Comment: You need to get the format of the date and time of the relevant locale first. And convert the data to a string in locale format for output like this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/roMzy.png
Demo here: https://gist.github.com/Torrecto/14797543f2d6fca0c9152c74edea1575

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to obtain the date using a different calendar. First, it is necessary to find the locale string associated with the calendar we want. For example, to print in the Hijri calendar, the Turkish locale (tr-TR) works well. After that, it is sufficient to use the GetDateFormatEx function as shown in the following example:

```
WCHAR formattedDate[256];
SYSTEMTIME systemTime, lt;
GetSystemTime(&systemTime);

GetDateFormatEx(L"tr-TR", DATE_SHORTDATE, &systemTime, NULL, formattedDate, sizeof(formattedDate) / sizeof(WCHAR), NULL);
wprintf(L"Date with alternative calendar: %s\n", formattedDate); //Date with alternative calendar: 6.09.2023

GetDateFormatEx(L"tr-TR", DATE_USE_ALT_CALENDAR | DATE_SHORTDATE, &systemTime, NULL, formattedDate, sizeof(formattedDate) / sizeof(WCHAR), NULL);
wprintf(L"Date with alternative calendar: %s\n", formattedDate); //Date with alternative calendar: 21.02.1445
```

Comment: Well done. You can accept your answer.